# Select column if it contains text?

Tags: r, dplyr

When working with an R tibble with several columns of varying data types and names, how do you correctly use `select_if` from the `dplyr` package to select only columns that contain text?

e.g. a tibble `tib` such as this one:

```
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
| PersonID | EmployeeID |    Date    | Value |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
|      123 | abc        | 10/12/2020 |  33.4 |
|      345 | fff        | 10/13/2020 |  44.2 |
|      567 | ddg        | 11/1/2020  |  60.2 |
+----------+------------+------------+-------+
```

How would I select only the PersonID and EmployeeID column using `select_if`?

So far, I have tried the following:

```
tib %>% select_if(~ grepl("ID", .))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error: `.p` is invalid.
x `.p` should return a single logical.
i `.p` returns a size 2000 <logical> for column `PersonID`.
```

Is the correct way to use `contains`?

I'm aware that `tib %>% select_if(is.character)` works, but how would I write a similar function as `is.character` to detect strings in the column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we wanted to `select` columns based on the column name patterns, use the `select_helpers`.  Based on the occurrence of 'ID', it seems that the OP wanted to select columns that `ends_with` 'ID' substring in column name

```
library(dplyr)
tib %>%
      select(ends_with('ID'))
```

If the column name have 'ID' anywhere

```
tib %>%
    select(contains('ID'))
```

Or for complex regular expressions, use `matches`

```
tib %>%
   select(matches("^[PE].*ID"))
```

---

With `dplyr` version `>= 1.0`, we can use `across` along with `select`

```
tib %>%
   select(where(is.character))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  EmployeeID Date      
#  <chr>      <chr>     
#1 abc        10/12/2020
#2 fff        10/13/2020
#3 ddg        11/1/2020
```

NOTE: Here, it is checking the `type` of the column values to `select` those.  Likewise, if we need to select columns having a particular values, we can use

```
tib %>%
    select(where(~ any(. == 'fff')))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  EmployeeID
#  <chr>     
#1 abc       
#2 fff       
#3 ddg
```

#### data

```
tib <- structure(list(PersonID = c(123, 345, 567), EmployeeID = c("abc", 
"fff", "ddg"), Date = c("10/12/2020", "10/13/2020", "11/1/2020"
), Value = c(33.4, 44.2, 60.2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `grepl`/`grep` to use regular expression :

```
tib[grepl('ID', names(tib))]
#With grep
#tib[grep('ID', names(tib))]
#  PersonID EmployeeID
#     <dbl> <chr>     
#1      123 abc       
#2      345 fff       
#3      567 ddg
```

If the value `'ID'` is always at the end we can also use `endsWith`.

```
tib[endsWith(names(tib), 'ID')]
```